# boost::spirit arithmetic formulas parser fails to compile

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi, boost-variant, boost-fusion

I am trying to write a spirit parser for arithmetic expression which fills an abstract syntax tree. The parser compiles if I am not trying to fill the AST, but fails (with one 24K error) in the current version. I am using clang++ 3.5.0 with -std=c++11, and running on Ubuntu 14.4.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapted.hpp>

#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_wrapper.hpp>

using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::pair;

using boost::spirit::qi::grammar;
using boost::spirit::qi::space_type;
using boost::spirit::qi::rule;

struct Term; // forward dec
typedef boost::recursive_wrapper<Term> RWTerm;
typedef pair<char, RWTerm> OpAndRWTerm;
typedef pair<RWTerm, vector<OpAndRWTerm> > Expr;
typedef boost::variant<Expr, double> Factor;
typedef pair<char, Factor> OpAndFactor;
struct Term : public pair<Factor, vector<OpAndFactor> >{};

template<typename It>
struct formula_parser : grammar<It, Expr(), space_type> {
  formula_parser() : formula_parser::base_type(expr_rule) {
    using boost::spirit::qi::double_;
    using boost::spirit::ascii::char_;

    factor_rule %= double_ | parenthesis_rule;
    parenthesis_rule %= '(' >> expr_rule >> ')';
    op_and_factor_rule %= char_("/*") >> factor_rule;
    term_rule %= factor_rule >> *op_and_factor_rule;
    op_and_term_rule %= char_("+-") >> term_rule;
    expr_rule %= term_rule >> *op_and_term_rule;
  }
  rule<It, OpAndRWTerm(), space_type> op_and_term_rule;
  rule<It, Expr(), space_type> expr_rule;
  rule<It, OpAndFactor(), space_type> op_and_factor_rule;
  rule<It, RWTerm(), space_type> term_rule;
  rule<It, Expr(), space_type> parenthesis_rule;
  rule<It, Factor(), space_type> factor_rule;
};

int main() {
  formula_parser<string::const_iterator> grammar;
}
```

What I understand from the error message is that fusion mixes up the Types Factor and RWTerm in the rule term_rule.

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It compiles for me if I change two things:

1. Since `Term` inherits from `std::pair`, `Term` is a **new** type. For this reason you need to apply `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` to `Term`, regardless whether this has been already done for `std::pair` in `<boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>`:

   ```
   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
       Term,
       (Factor, first)
       (std::vector<OpAndFactor>, second)
   )
   ```

   Alternatively, you could make `Term` a standalone struct with two members and then apply `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` on that:

   ```
   struct Term { Factor f; std::vector<OpAndFactor>  o;};

   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
       Term,
       (Factor, f)
       (std::vector<OpAndFactor>, o)
   )
   ```

   By the way: You have to fully qualify `std::vector` here, because the following [will not compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fda7b052d8409255):

   ```
   using std::vector;
   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
       Term,
       (Factor, f)
       (vector<OpAndFactor>, o)
   )
   ```
2. Use `Term` instead of `RWTerm` when declaring `term_rule`:

   ```
   rule<It, Term(), space_type> term_rule;
   ```

**full code:**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapted.hpp>

#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_wrapper.hpp>

using boost::spirit::qi::grammar;
using boost::spirit::qi::space_type;
using boost::spirit::qi::rule;

struct Term; // forward dec
typedef boost::recursive_wrapper<Term> RWTerm;
typedef std::pair<char, RWTerm> OpAndRWTerm;
typedef std::pair<RWTerm, std::vector<OpAndRWTerm> > Expr;
typedef boost::variant<Expr, double> Factor;
typedef std::pair<char, Factor> OpAndFactor;
struct Term : public std::pair<Factor, std::vector<OpAndFactor> >{};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Term,
    (Factor, first)
    (std::vector<OpAndFactor>, second)
)


template<typename It>
struct formula_parser : grammar<It, Expr(), space_type> {
  formula_parser() : formula_parser::base_type(expr_rule) {
    using boost::spirit::qi::double_;
    using boost::spirit::ascii::char_;

    factor_rule %= double_ | parenthesis_rule;
    parenthesis_rule %= '(' >> expr_rule >> ')';
    op_and_factor_rule %= char_("/*") >> factor_rule;
    term_rule %= factor_rule >> *op_and_factor_rule;
    op_and_term_rule %= char_("+-") >> term_rule;
    expr_rule %= term_rule >> *op_and_term_rule;
  }
  rule<It, OpAndRWTerm(), space_type> op_and_term_rule;
  rule<It, Expr(), space_type> expr_rule;
  rule<It, OpAndFactor(), space_type> op_and_factor_rule;
  rule<It, Term(), space_type> term_rule;
  rule<It, Expr(), space_type> parenthesis_rule;
  rule<It, Factor(), space_type> factor_rule;
};

int main() {
  formula_parser<std::string::const_iterator> grammar;
}
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0eb7d31294392f5)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks - it works ! what's wrong with using inheritance from pair ?

Comment: @DavidLehavi I updated the answer with an explanation

Comment: thanks for the details (only after comparing you code with my previous attempts I realized one has to fully qualify the vector)

Comment: @DavidLehavi I try to avoid `using namespace...` or `using ns::type...` wherever possible, since it might get you into trouble with macros.  In this case, I think `std::vector` is more readable since there are similarly named `vectors` such as `boost::mpl::vector`, `boost::fusion::vector` etc. which could distract the reader of that code.

Comment: Recent boost can also just `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Term, first, second)`: [further cleanups](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e9f936e506f0d93)

Comment: @sehe good to know! which boost version introduced this feature?

Comment: I'm not sure. 57 or 58 I think

Comment: @sehe I found it in the [changelog of 1.58](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_58_0.html): *"
New ADAPT_STRUCT, ADAPT_ADT, ADAPT_ASSOC_ that deduce the members types (#9516)"*